# Serialization of Strongly Typed Datasets

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, appfabric

Does anyone know a way to make a strongly typed dataset (Hey not my idea to use them) serializable so that I can store them using AppFabric Server as a Session State provider?  I have been using InProc Session state for some time now and haven't had any issues with this.  As soon as I moved the Session state out to AppFabric Server I am getting some issues with strongly typed datasets.  I keep getting an error telling me that my datasets aren't serializable.  I have checked and they have the `Serializable` attribute on them and they only contain serializable data types (`int`, `string`, etc.)  Any thougnts?

Edit: Here is the Stack Trace:

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The constructor to deserialize an object of type ''DataSetClasses.MyStronglyTypedDataset'' was not found. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The constructor to deserialize an object of type ''DataSetClasses.MyStronglyTypedDataset''  was not found.     at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.GetConstructor(RuntimeType t, RuntimeType[] ctorParams)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)     at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)     at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()     at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)     at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name)     at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name)     at System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.get_Item(String name)     at appt.T2SharedLibrarySetup.btnSave_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Application\ProblemFile.aspx.vb:line 331     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent`

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace you're getting?

Comment: This SO article may be relevant:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891447/how-to-serialize-de-serialize-a-custom-dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try serializing / deserializing the object to a byte array first before you attempt to put it into session (and thence to AppFabric). Here is an example.

```
        private static BinaryFormatter formatter = null;

    private static Byte[] Serialize(object entity)
    {
        Logger.LogDebug(Category.Cache, "Serializing");
        Byte[] bytes;
        if (formatter == null) formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, entity);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    private static object DeSerialize(Byte[] bytes)
    {
        #region Sanitation
        if (bytes == null) { throw new System.ArgumentNullException("bytes"); }
        #endregion
        Logger.LogDebug(Category.Cache, "DeSerializing");
        object obj;
        if (formatter == null) formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        return obj;
    }
```

After you get the object back from the deserializer attempt to cast it back to your typed dataset type.

Comment: This is a strongly typed dataset created from within Visual Studio by adding a dataset and then dragging and dropping a table/sproc onto the design surface.  It seems counter intuitive that I should need to manually Serialize/Deserialize this built in Visual Studio functionality.

Comment: The reason I'm suggesting this is that if you binary serialize it yourself, you remove the dependency on the appfabric client examining your object and trying to figure out how to serialize it itself. For instance, if the client finds WCF data annotation attributes on any members of your classes, it will attempt to use the NetDataContractSerializer which you may not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataSet.ReadXML() or WriteXML() functions to achieve desired functionality.